# Android - Image Shared element transition between activities broken when keyboard open

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I have 2 activities Activity A and Activity B.

on Activity A has EditText and ImageView.

on Activity B has ImageView.

when i clicked on the ImageView in Activity A i used shared element to make a smooth animation between Activity A to B.

My problem starts when i clicked on ImageView in Activity A when the keyboard open.

what happens is the Shared element broken and the animation looks bad.

what can i do to fix it?
maybe something with android:windowSoftInputMode?

Edit :

when i clicked to open Activity B i call before that to hide keyboard like this:

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
InputMethodManager imm = 
(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handler can help you something like that:

```
    hideKeyboardMethod()
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //make the transition 
        }
     },200);
    }
```